# Extract all body texts with Scrapy (only texts)

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to read all the texts in the **body** of a page to make some string comparisons.

I tried the options below, but they return a lot of information that I don't need, like `<script>`:

```
response.xpath('// body').extract()
response.xpath ('//body//p//text()').extract()
response.css ('::text').extract()
```

The ideal would be to return only all body texts, without tags and nothing else, just text, example:

This being a part of the body:

```
[...]

<h4 class="h4">
    <a href="/about/" class="header__menu-nav-arrowed-link link link--black link--black-hover-green" target="">
        <span>Company</span>
        <svg class="icon icon-slider-arrow-left header__menu-nav-arrowed-link-icon">
            <use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-slider-arrow-right"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
</h4>


</li>
    <li class="contact-info__item">
    <a class="link contact-info__link" href="tel:99999999999 ">
        <svg class="icon icon--telephone contact-info__link-icon contact-info__link-icon--phone">
            <use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-phone"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="contact-info__link-text">9 (999) 99-99-99</span>
    </a>
</li>

[...]
```

Then it would result in a list with these and the other body items:

```
['Company', '9 (999) 99-99-99']
```

However, if it is possible to obtain the body as a list, where each line (or tag) is an item in that list, it also serves. Based on the first example, a "per line" list would look like this:

```
['<h4 class="h4">',
'<a href="/about/" class="header__menu-nav-arrowed-link link',
'link--black link--black-hover-green" target="">',
'<span>Company</span>', '<svg class="icon icon-slider-arrow-left header__menu-nav-arrowed-link-icon">',
'<use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-slider-arrow-right"></use>',
'</svg>',
'</a>',
'</h4>']
```

**EDITED:**
Or, capture all the texts on the page except those within `<script></script>`

Comment: Can you be abit more precise about what the desired result is ? as what data you require specifically? I'm not altogether clear on that. Sounds as if you're wanting to put large chunks of HTML into a list.

Comment: I have a few phones within a list, so I need to go through all the HTML on the page and check that each string on this page is contained in that list. And would you like to do that with Scrapy instead of bs4, is it possible?

Comment: I just edited in the question:
or else capture all texts on the page except those within `<script></script>`

This would also serve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach will probably return data in a unstructured way, where all text is a item on a list. This is usually not useful at all, but if that's what you are looking for you can try this:

```
response.xpath('//body//*[not(self::script)]/text()').getall()
```

Let me know if it solved the issue.

Comment: It really works! What about excluding `<script>` and `<a>` tags?
I tried this below, but only `<script>` is deleted: `response.xpath('//body//*[not(self::script|self::a)]/text()').getall()`

Comment: That syntax looks correct, not sure why it didn't work. You can  try `//body//*[not(self::script) and not(self::a)]/text()`

Comment: The way I posted and yours works on some pages, but as I need it to work on all, I'll filter the `<a>` manually, so I'll mark it as **resolved**. Thanks again, today you are saving my day hehe

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to parse the HTML response, Beautiful Soup is a good library to accomplish this - https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

As a quick implementation, if all you are looking to do is get the text from the body. Note the need to strip blank lines out, and if you want as a dict, you'll have to convert. -

```
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        import os
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
        text = soup.get_text()
        text = os.linesep.join([s for s in text.splitlines() if s])
        print(text)
```

With this imput -

```
<h4 class="h4">
    <a href="/about/" class="header__menu-nav-arrowed-link link link--black link--black-hover-green" target="">
        <span>Company</span>
        <svg class="icon icon-slider-arrow-left header__menu-nav-arrowed-link-icon">
            <use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-slider-arrow-right"></use>
        </svg>
    </a>
</h4>


</li>
    <li class="contact-info__item">
    <a class="link contact-info__link" href="tel:99999999999 ">
        <svg class="icon icon--telephone contact-info__link-icon contact-info__link-icon--phone">
            <use xlink:href="/local/templates/.default/img/icon-font/icon-font.svg#icon-phone"></use>
        </svg>
        <span class="contact-info__link-text">9 (999) 99-99-99</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

You will get this output -

```
Company
9 (999) 99-99-99
```

Without knowing more about your specific use case, hopefully this helps!

Comment: I have a few phones within a list, so I need to go through all the HTML on the page and check that each string on this page is contained in that list. And would you like to do that with Scrapy instead of bs4, is it possible?

Comment: In theory yes, I defaulted to bs4 as I know it can solve this problem. Is there any limitation that means you have to use scrapy to parse the html?

Comment: There is, I need the pages to be lowered asynchronously, and Scrapy brings this up.

Comment: I just edited in the question:
or else capture all texts on the page except those within `<script></script>`

This would also serve!